How to share cookies between subdomains?
I have three applications: A, B, and C. The user logs in through application A. On successful login, I set a bunch of cookies. The code for the same is,
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

cookies().set(USER_ID, user_id, {
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
})  
After I read to application B, I tried to read this cookie using the following code,

const cookies = useCookies();

const user_id = cookies.get(USER_ID) as string;

import { useCookies } from 'next-client-cookies';

Each application is hosted on a dedicated subdomain. The problem is, that I cannot read the USER_ID from applications B and C.
In .env:
DOMAIN='.example.com'
NOTE:
A: a.example.com
B: b.example.com
C: c.example.com
I have hosted all three under the AWS single EC2 instance.
I have tried js-cookie, and cookies-next as well. I am so confused, what's wrong? Can someone please help?

Especially if they're all running on the same instance, can you use path-based routing instead of host-based routing for these applications; https://example.com/a/ and so on?  Then CORS and cross-domain cookie rules wouldn't apply, because all three applications are on the same domain.

The only reason to separate them is for security reasons.

If httpOnly is set to true, you cannot access the cookie from the frontend (client-side).
cookies().set(USER_ID, user_id, {
domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
path: "/",
secure: true,
httpOnly: false,
sameSite: "none",
maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
})
